# Tricking someone into being the willing target of a spell

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting

Some spells, I believe, require a willing target. Others only allow a save if the target is unwilling. I am wondering if you can tell a target that you are going to cast one spell and then actually cast a different one.

Can you trick a target creature into being willing to be a target by lying about what spell you are going to cast? Can the target tell the exact nature of an incoming spell for willing/unwillingness/save purposes?

Comment: I've moved the titular question into the body. The title is only meant to be an indicative summary of the body: it's not meant to contain the question itself, and definitely shouldn't contain an entirely substantially different question.

Comment: Just as an FYI, I voted to undelete your question because it was still a good question to ask. Duplicates are okay and actually can make it easier for others to find simply because it's more then one way of asking the same thing